# Sitemap generation does not save file to storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, dokku, sitemap-generator-gem

I'm just getting a sitemap going with the rails [gem](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator) and am having trouble generating a sitemap in production.

Running the rake command: `rake sitemap:refresh` in development creates the `sitemap.xml.gz` file in the public folder. I navigate to `localhost:3000/sitemap.xml.gz` and get it downloads the zipped file.

When I run it in production (Heroku-like command line with Dokku on a Digital Ocean VM) I get:

```
+ sitemap.xml.gz                                           6 links /  450 Bytes
Sitemap stats: 6 links / 1 sitemaps / 0m00s

Pinging with URL 'https://www.myapp.com/sitemap.xml.gz':
  Successful ping of Google
  Successful ping of Bing
```

It appears the file has been created, so I navigate to `www.myapp.com/sitemap.xml.gz` and get a 404 response.

Server say:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/sitemap.xml.gz"):
```

It appears that this request is hitting the Rails stack when it should be served by Nginx. I just checked to see if the file exists:

```
FileTest.exists?("public/sitemap.xml.gz")
```

It returns `false` so it seems like the sitemap is not actually saved on file. Is there a possibility my file system is read-only right now? How could I test that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a dokku related "issue". Dokku uses Heroku buildpacks, and this yields a read-only file system like on Heroku.

I'd be curious to know if there's a way to modify that behavior in Dokku (seems unlikely if using Heroku buildpacks), but that's a bit out of my league.

I think the best solution to this problem is the same as on Heroku - using Amazon S3.

The `sitemap_generator` gem has [docs](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/wiki/Generate-Sitemaps-on-read-only-filesystems-like-Heroku) on how to set this up.

Answer (score 2):

With the new dokku docker-options plugin, you could append persistent storage/volume from your host machine into you container.

First create a local directory in your host machine.

```
mkdir <path/to/dir>
```

Then add the following docker-options in dokku

```
dokku docker-options:add <app> deploy,run -v <path/to/host/dir>:<path/to/container/public/sub/dir>:rw
```

On your config/sitemap.rb file, add the following lines

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'public/sitemap/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = 'sitemap/'
```

The sitemap:refresh rake task should write into the sitemap sub folder within the public folder.

This would also allow sitemap_generator to ping the search engine with the right address to your sitemap.xml.gz file.

Feel free to give this a try.

Comment: Cool that dokku continues to expand, thanks for the tip. I'm not using Dokku much right now so probably won't get to try this out, but I'd be interested to hear how it works out.